# Php unserialized a serialized json string

Tags: php

After a http post in c# to php am getting an output of the form
   in the code i have

```
    public function actionSubmitInspection(){
       $data = $_POST;

        return (array)$data["check_comments"];

    }
```

now am getting a result of the form

```
[
 "[{\"id\":26,\"comment\":\"89oiu\"},{\"id\":27,\"comment\":\"comment 2\"}]"
]
```

as from my try typecasting array doesnt creating the array, How can i convert the serialized string to an array or an object.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Did you try `json_decode($result[0]);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use json_decode function.

```
public function actionSubmitInspection(){
       $data = $_POST;
        // replace it
        //return (array)$data["check_comments"];
        return json_decode($data["check_comments"]);

    }
```

Out put will be array of objects.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 26
            [comment] => 89oiu
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 27
            [comment] => comment 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

> as from my try typecasting array doesnt creating the array

Yes, it creates an array but the array it creates contains the JSON text.

You need to parse the JSON in order to restore the data structures it encodes. PHP provides the function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this purpose. I recommend you pass `TRUE` as the second argument to `json_decode()` to get back arrays (otherwise it creates `stdClass` objects that are just arrays with a fancy syntax and limited options for processing).

```
// Assuming the value of $data['check_comments'] is:
// "[{\"id\":26,\"comment\":\"89oiu\"},{\"id\":27,\"comment\":\"comment 2\"}]"
$output = json_decode($data['check_comments']);

print_r($output);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [comment] => 89oiu
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [comment] => comment 2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_decode($data["check_comments"])` the output will be an **array of stdClass objects**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 26
            [comment] => 89oiu
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 27
            [comment] => comment 2
        )

)
```

or passing `true` on second param, `json_decode($data["check_comments"], true)` and the output will be an **array of arrays**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [comment] => 89oiu
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [comment] => comment 2
        )

)
```